# How do I change the case of a string in C++?

Tags: c++, string, case

I have a string that may contain numbers as well as upper and lower case letters. I need to convert all the uppercase letters to lowercase and vice versa. How would one go about this?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: LOL yeah it is. However, I figured out how to go about this using Matthew Iselins' advice.

Comment: `for(char &c:str) c^=32;`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Iterate the string and use `isupper()` to determine if each character is uppercase or not. If it's uppercase, convert it to lowercase using `tolower()`. If it's not uppercase, convert it to uppercase using `toupper()`.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a way to do it without boost:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>

char change_case (char c) {
    if (std::isupper(c)) 
        return std::tolower(c); 
    else
        return std::toupper(c); 
}

int main() {
    std::string str;
    str = "hEllo world";
    std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), change_case);
    std::cout << str;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Minor nitpick - change_case instead of swap_letters?

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the string and add or subtract the appropriate number from each alpha character so that the ASCII value is resolved to the opposite case ASCII value.

Comment: if you're going to do it that way, you might as well flip bits..i forget which one it is, but one of em will swap the case.

Answer (score 1):

You can flip the 32 bit as well: works with ASCII characters thus:

```
char flipcase(char x)
{
   if( ::isalpha(x) )
   {
      return x ^ 32;
   }
}
```

You can also use a table. Create a static table then

```
char flipcase( char x )
{
   return fliptable[x];
}
```

The latter method having the advantage of being able to be used for foreign character sets too as long as they are not multi-byte - it won't work for that. You can make a similar table for wchar_t characters with whatever character set you are using. Storing the table requires a small amount of memory use if sizeof your character is no more than 2, although it would use too much for UTF-32 and the lookup time is trivial. Of course in reality you would store a small struct for each character with its traits.

With either of the above you would use std::transform.

And now the really clever bit: std::transform can use a class (functor) as well as a plain function. For multi-byte characters we can therefore store the state as long as the replacement character will always have the same first element. If that is not the case then transform won't work with the regular iterators. However you could write a custom iterator to handle multi-byte character strings that would iterate up a printable character at a time (The iterator would have to dereference to multi-byte characters representing a symbol).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    //Changecase to Uppercase
    string var = "This is a String.";
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < var.length(); i++){
        if (islower(var[i]))
            var[i] = toupper(var[i]);
    }
    cout << var << endl;
    /*
    Output:
    THIS IS A STRING.
    */
    //Changecase to Lowercase
    var = "This is a String.";
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < var.length(); i++){
        if (isupper(var[i]))
            var[i] = tolower(var[i]);
    }
    cout << var << endl;
    /*
    Output:
    this is a string.
    */
    //Flip the case
    var = "This is a String.";
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < var.length(); i++){
        if (isupper(var[i]))
            var[i] = tolower(var[i]);
        else
            var[i] = toupper(var[i]);
    }
    cout << var << endl;
    /*
    Output:
    tHIS IS A sTRING.
    */

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard C++ method to do this is as follows:

```
std::string lower = "this is my string to be uppercased";
std::locale loc; //get the locale from the system.
auto facet = std::use_facet<std::ctype<char>>(loc);
facet.toupper(&lower[0], &lower[0] + lower.length()); //they didn't provide a C++ iterator interface, so pointer arithmetic it is.  
std::cout << lower << std::endl;
```

this outputs:

```
 THIS IS MY STRING TO BE UPPERCASED
```

there's also a `facet.toupper()` to handle converting lowercase to uppercase, and `facet.widen` to convert from char to wchar_t, and `facet.narrow` to convert from wchar_t to char.

Answer (score -1):

```
char *str = "this is a test string";
while(*str != '\0') {
    if(*str <= 'Z' && *str >= 'A') {
       *str += 32;
    } else if(*str >= 'a' && *str <= 'z') {
       *str -= 32;
    }
 str++;
}
```

Not secure at all, just giving you the idea.
This might be very helpful for this homework:

[image]

Comment: This is not an appropriate C++ answer, imo.

Comment: I agree, this won't work on unicode or any other non ASCI chars, but if he'd understand the idea behind this code, it'd be a trival task to add support for ever other charset, secure it, prevent heap corruption, etc..

Comment: Without an else thrown in there, this will convert upper case to lower case, and then change it right back to upper case.  Also, why don't you use character constants ('a','z','A','Z') for better readability?

Comment: @PigBen, it won't convert back the uppercase to lowercase as the cursor will advance it's position by 1.

Comment: @Karim:  Correct, it won't convert the uppercase back to lowercase, but it will convert the lowercase back to uppercase, like I said.  Test it if you don't believe me.

Comment: Not secure? Will possibly core dump/access violation as you are trying to modify a literal. char test[] = "This is a test string"; char* str = &test[0]; then your code would work

Comment: -1. char * and C-functions dealing with it like strXXX, printf, scanf, etc have been responsible for let's say 99% of all bugs in the world. Don't use it in C++!