# Output "Valid" if input does not contain character 'S'. Otherwise, output "Invalid"

Tags: c++

I am very new to C++ and am trying to complete an assignment involving loops. The goal of the activity is to print "valid" for passwords not containing the character "S" and "invalid" for those that do.

Here's the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  bool validPassword;
  string codeWord;
  int passLength;

  cin >> codeWord;
  passLength = codeword.length();
  for (int i = 0; i <= passLength; ++i) {

    if (codeWord.at(i) != 'S') {
      validPassword = true;   
      continue;               
    }                         
    else {
      validPassword = false;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (validPassword) {
    cout << "Valid" << endl;
  }
  else {
    cout << "Invalid" << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's your question?  But although your code looks at every character, the choice "valid" or "invalid" is only affected by the last character.

Comment: Tactical note: [Don't post images of code.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) It's one of the absolute fastest ways to to get a question closed and removed. Replace the code with a [mre] version of your program and we'll see about reopening the question.

Comment: Use the `find` method:  `if (codeWord.find('S') == std::string::npos) validPassword = true;`

Comment: Watch the case. If you are entering passwords with lowercase `'s'` the test will fail. Maybe you want an AND (`&&`) there checking both options, or you could [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084458/how-do-i-change-the-case-of-a-string-in-c) the password to lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

I'm kinda new to c++ as well, but this code I made worked for it. I used 'codeWord.find()' instead of cycling through all of the characters in the string. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    bool validPassword;

    string codeWord;

    
    cin >> codeWord;

    if(codeWord.find("8") == string::npos) {
        validPassword = true;
    }
    else{
        validPassword = false;
   }

   if (validPassword) {
        cout << "Valid" << endl;
   }
   else {
        cout << "Invalid" << endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```